# onclick handler doesnt work after jquery AJAX html injection

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am injecting some HTML with ajax into my page but the `onclick` handler on a part of that injected HTML doesn't seem to work...

basically this image...

```
< img class="close_row" src="img/close.gif"/>
```

my jquery goes like...

```
$('.close_row').click(function() {
    // some code to close the row
});
```

the original function to open the row and inject the html works fine, am i overlooking something here?

Comment: use the live handler for dynamically added elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.delegate()` instead.

`delegate()` was introduced to overcome `live()`'s shortcomings and `live()` would have been completely removed if it wasn't for the fact that it would have broken a lot of code.

Differences between `live()` and `delegate()`: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/

API: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('.close_row').live('click', function() { // some code to close the row });
```

`.click` binds the event to all current elements, whereas `.live` will automatically bind the event to newly created elements.